# how to identify the last logged in user in Windows 7 / Windows 10

Tags: windows, command

I am a user in a domain where there are lot of cloud machines available.Now the problem is these machines can be logged in by any people .Though I can restart these machines using the command shutdown /r /f /t 0 -m  .Before doing so I want to know who was the user logged in to that machine.Is there any command for that?

Answer (score 1):

Check event logs, they're different based upon OS version. Use PowerShell and WMI to find who's currently logged on and at what time:

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_UserProfile | Select-Object -Property SID,LocalPath,Loaded,LastUseTime,@{Name=”Account”;Expression={((New-Object -TypeName System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier($_.SID)).Translate([System.Security.Principal.NTAccount])).Value}}
```

This blog has all kinds of ways to look at who's logged onto the system:
[Determining the Dominant User and Setting the ManagedBy Computer Attribute](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askpfeplat/2016/07/12/determining-the-dominant-user-and-setting-the-managedby-computer-attribute/)